# NoReverseMatch at Error using Django and D3

Tags: python, django, d3.js

I'm trying to create a graph in d3 using django 1.4.5 (I can't upgrade it to the newer version).

The logic is the following

1. go to localhost:8000/usage/graphs
2. This will load the html file (graphs.html) which will call another view
3. The View ('use_count_by_month') produces data that is passed to the html page as a list of dictionaries

   I can confirm the view exports a dictionary, but I can't get the html to load the data.

**Error Msg:**

**Reverse for ''use_count_by_month'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.**

This is my code:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=patterns('usage.views',
   url(r'^graph/', 'graph', name='graph'),
   url(r'^use_count_by_month$/', 'use_count_by_month', name='data')
)
```

views.py

```
def graph(request):
return render(request,'usage/graph.html')

def use_count_by_month(request):
   data=[{"count_items": 731, "month": "2014-01-01"}, {"count_items":404, "month": "2014-02-01"}]
json_string=json.dumps(data)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

From the html file...

```
d3.json("{% url 'use_count_by_month'  %}" ,function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.month = parseDate(d.month);
d.count_items = +d.count_items;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL pattern has `name='data'` so you could change the URL tag to

```
{% url 'data'  %}
```

Alternatively, you can change the URL pattern to `name='use_count_by_month'` and keep the URL tag as.

```
{% url 'use_count_by_month'  %}
```

Comment: Negative :( I went for  `{% url 'data' %} `  and get the following: **Reverse for ''data'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.**